# create a zip file from webservice REST java

Tags: java, xml, rest, zip

I'm trying to develop a REST webservice to generate an XML file.
it's done actually, but what i'm trying to achieve is, to create a zip file with the xml fil inside to be downloaded to the cient.

Comment: And what code have you written to achieve this?

Comment: Good luck in this issue! Come back when you have some result!

Answer (score 0):

In fact with a good webserver (tomcat) or with an apache revers proxy all the responses could be gzipped automatically. Check in your browser network console to see if it is activate. In the header : Content-Encoding:gzip